# Encode python string directly into bytearray?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python, you can do:

```
b = bytearray(100)
b[0:3] = 'one'.encode()
b[17:20] = 'two'.encode()
```

This, however, creates an intermediate bytes() object, which is leading to suboptimal performance.

Is there anything like encode_into() that will encode a string directly into a bytearray?

Comment: This is an [interesting read](http://bugs.python.org/issue3982); particularly when it gets to [struct.pack](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html). Not an answer, but it may help.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're working in python3.x, otherwise `b[0:3] = 'one'` works just fine.

For python3.x, you can use the `b` string prefix:

```
b[0:3] = b'one'  # parser creates a bytes object, not a string.
```

Comment: Fair point, but that only works for string literals.  I have a user-specified string.